# Exclude file that matches in project folder

Tags: gulp, glob

I have several js files located in a library and some matching js files in a project folder. I want to work with these files in a gulp task.

```
+--project/
|  +--core/
|     |--actor.js
+--library/
   +--core/
      |--actor.js
      |--like.js
```

Normally, I would do something like `gulp.src(['./project/**/*.js','./library/**/*.js']` and then `concat` or `uglify` as needed, but this would join both versions of `actor.js` in the final result. I want to exclude the `library/core/actor.js` file so the final result only include `project/core/actor.js` and `library/core/like.js`.

Is there anyway to exclude a file or files from the library that's present in the matching location in the project folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const filter = require('gulp-filter');
const fs = require('fs');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const path = require('path');


gulp.task('default', function () {

  const filterDuplicates = filter(function (file) {

    // console.log(path.basename(file.base));  returns "project" or "library"
    // don't filter out if in "project" folder

    if (path.basename(file.base) == "project") return true;

    else {
      // make a full path but with "project" replacing "library"
      let projectTestPath = path.join(file.cwd, "project", file.relative);

      // if the the "library" file exists in the "project" path filter out
      if (fs.existsSync(projectTestPath)) return false;
    }
    return true;
  });

  return gulp.src(['./project/**/*.js', './library/**/*.js'])

    .pipe(filterDuplicates)
    .pipe(concat("concat.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

For a more complicated but similar question and answer, see my answer at [Gulp remove duplicates if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45081698/gulp-remove-duplicates-if-exists/45096031#45096031).